# How to turn off maven dependency:analyze-only failOnWarning

Tags: java, maven-2, configuration

I'm building a java project with maven-2 and due to some dependencies listed, and others not listed, in the pom.xml file and the fact that failOnWarning is set to true in the dependency:analyze-only mojo configuration I am not able to build the project without using the maven -fn flag.

Here is more detail.

```
$ mvn install -X
...snip...
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.0:analyze-only' -->
...snip...
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnWarning = true
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreNonCompile = true
...snip...
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] [dependency:analyze-only {execution: default}]
[INFO] Used declared dependencies found:
[INFO]    javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO]    javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    flexson:json:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
...snip...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Dependency problems found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is this:

How can I set failOnWarning = false without changing the pom.xml file for the project?
- The pom.xml file is checked into source control and others on the project don't need to change it to build the project so I expect there is something different about my maven setup.
- We are all using maven 2.2.1 with the same settings.xml file.

Comment: FYI, I found out that doing mvn install hasn't been working for anyone on the team, but mvn package has due to failOnWarning being true.  I am going to update our pom.xml file so we can do mvn install again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit over the top, but could you not specify it as a property? e.g. something like `<failOnWarnings>${config.failOnWarning}</failOnWarning>`

Specify the property in the properties section of your POM to be true. Then you can override it to be false when you run from the command-line.

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I have seen that option, but my preference would be to not change the pom.xml file in order to find out why my maven has failOnWarning set to true while others on the project have it set to false and also not to have to change the pom.xml file in source control just for me and no one else.

Comment: @Paul I assume there is some reason you can't just edit the file locally without checking it into source control for the purposes of your investigation? If that's the case I don't know, sorry!

Comment: Hi Phil.  I have edited the pom.xml file without checking it in and that fixed the build problem on my machine.  I was just hoping for a -D argument to mvn or other conf change that would change failOnWarning to false.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just found out that no one on the team can do an mvn install without -fn.  They have all been doing mvn package instead.  So, I am going to update our pom.xml in source control file so that we can do mvn install.  Thanks @Phill Sacre.

Answer (score 3):

Add `-Dmdep.analyze.skip` to your command. Supported as of 2.7.0

> `<skip>`
>
> boolean
>
> 2.7
>
> Skip plugin execution completely.
>
> Default value is: false.
>
> User property is: mdep.analyze.skip.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-only-mojo.html